# how to return a devserver for custom configuration while setting up cypress component testing with custom devserver

Tags: reactjs, vite, rollup, cypress-component-test-runner, devserver

I have a react component library which is bundled using Rollup. I want to add cypress component testing so that I can unit test those components using cypress.
Cypress currently supports setting automatic configuration for React using either `webpack' bundler or` vite` bundler.

```
export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    devServer: {
      bundler: 'vite', // or it can be webpack
      framework:'react',
    }
  },
```

if we have anything apart from webpack or vite, we need to return custom-server instance from the devserver function as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/component-testing/component-framework-configuration#Custom-Dev-Server)

```
module.exports = defineConfig({
  component: {
    devServer(cypressConfig) {
      // return dev server instance or a promise that resolves to
      // a dev server instance here
    },
  },
})
```

I am not understanding how to return that devserver instance.

Answer (score 1):

Function syntax:

```
import { devServer } from '@cypress/vite-dev-server'
import { defineConfig } from 'cypress'

export default defineConfig({
  component: {
    devServer(devServerConfig) {
      return devServer({
        ...devServerConfig,
        framework: 'react',
        viteConfig: require('./vite.config.js')
      })
    }
  }
})
```

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/tree/master/npm/vite-dev-server#readme

Comment: Thank you, David! will have to check. will update not a priority as of now. but thank you again